# ggplot legend created by group cannot be edited

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure out how to control the legend that is created by the group parameter in the first ggplot line. I like using group because it makes the confidence bands much smoother with geom_ribbon later on. If I just use colour=tx.f, the confidence bands look very weird and are either jagged or have an oitline. The only problem with using the group=tx.f option is that it creates another legend that I can't seem to get rid of or edit. Any leads on how to edit this legend?? I've tried a ton of things but I can't seem to edit that legend or remove it from my plot.

```
stai_plot<-ggplot(aes(x = cwk, y = estimate__, group=tx.f, colour=tx.f, 
linetype=tx.f), data = plt_dat_stai) +
geom_point(aes(y = stai), data = subj_marginals_stai, 
         position = position_dodge(width=0.2),
         alpha = 0.4) + 
geom_line(aes(cwk,estimate__),size=1)+
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lower__,ymax=upper__), alpha=.1, colour=NA)+
scale_y_continuous(name = "STAI", limits = c(30,75))+
theme_minimal()+
labs(color='Treatment\nType', group="Treatment Type") +
scale_x_continuous(name="Treatment Week", breaks=c(-3,0,3), labels=c("Week 1", "Week 3", "Week 6"))+
scale_color_manual(labels = c("Waitlist", "Integrative"),values=c("black",  "blue"))
stai_plot
```

The result I get is below:

[image: See that there are two legends]

Comment: Which legend do you want to remove? The one named `tx.f` or `Treatment Type`? The issue here is not really grouping, it's that you mapped a variable to two aesthetics, color and linetype.

Comment: Can you share your data using `dput()`?

Comment: Next time I will! I wan'ted to remove the tx.f legend. @Luke Hayden 's response worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the linetype legend. If you want to remove a single legend, you can specify this with guide(). In your case, adding this to the end of your plot code should solve it.

```
+guides(linetype = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Luke! I must have added the group and linetype mapping at the same time and got them confused. Rookie mistake.